# How to configure API to accept JWT token but validation should happen through Another API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, token

In WEB API, 
How to use `[Authorize]` attribute to make it work if validating token (JWT token) through another WEB API.
It works while I am using JWT Authentication within same API.